# What is true meaning of Sympathie?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request

What does "Küssen bei Sympathie" mean? The English translation doesn't make sense.

Comment: There's by far not enough context in this question to be able to answer.

Comment: If the English translation doesn't make sense you must have translated wrong. Note that German *Sympathie* and English *sympathy* are false friends: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Sympathie *Bei* is also troublesome (see under II.3):  https://www.dwds.de/wb/bei#d-1-1-2

Comment: Which English translation doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Sympathie](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Sympathie)*** affection, fondness; goodwill

You sentence seems to come from the context of sex workers offering services in advertisements. There, *küssen bei Sympathie* means that the prostitute is willing to kiss you if (s)he feels comfortable with you and/or likes you and/or you appear well-groomed and "clean".

Here is a *Spiegel* article that uses the phrase in the title of an article on prostitution during the "Corona crisis": ["Küssen bei Sympathie": Warum Prostituierte trotz Corona arbeiten – und wie](https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/sexarbeit-in-corona-krise-warum-prostituierte-weiter-arbeiten-a-f3b5f007-a153-4f34-b20e-792c782b3c05)

Other Google finds lead to punter forums and ads by prostitutes that I don't want to link here. You can easily find them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Both Sympathie and sympathy come from the greek word συμπάθεια, meaning *having an emotionally positive stance for someone*, or showing them love (preference if you will).

Just like in Greek, Sympathie in German means *affection and love for someone*. A synonym for that in German would be `die Zuneigung (Sg.)`.

The fact that the English translate to sorrow for someone's misfortune, is because through the translation the actual meaning has been altered.

Comment: I find this a bit misleading. "Sympathie" isn't more than just appreciation for a person. "Having an emotionally positive stance for someone" is quite a fitting description. "Zuneigung" and "affection" are a bit stronger imo. "Love" is definitively a much stronger word and not a synonym at all.